# Flask redirect not working how do I fixed it?

Tags: python, flask, redirect, flask-login

I want to redirect if val is true

```
            if val:
                print("val true",val)
                return redirect(url_for('users.verify_sms_otp'))
```

my redirect function

```
@users.route('/verify_account/verify_sms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def verify_sms_otp():
    return render_template('user/EnterMobileOTP.html')
```

when execute this code my url is work fine , but another url also execute which I don't define .
My define path is :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2021 07:46:22] "GET /verify_account/verify_sms HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I don't define this.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2021 07:46:22] "GET /verify_account/undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But both are execute as a result I don't get my exact path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I fixed it, actually I define

```
window.location = 'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/verify_account/' + data.token
```

this in my ajax's json respose. that's why after execute redirect, ajax response automatically place this path.